# Can I iterate through a string using for c := range<string> but only use the character and not the index?

Tags: go

Basically I want to iterate through a string getting each character and doing something with that character. However when I try to loop through the string I have to provide one variable for the index of the character and one for the character itself ie. `for pos, char := range myString {*do something*}`. How do I do simply assign the character itself without having to assign the index?

Comment: the "Tour of Go" is a very good place to start learning the language https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/17

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `range` form of the for loop iterates over a slice or map.

When ranging over a slice, two values are returned for each iteration:

1. The first is the index of the slice;
2. The second is a copy of the element at that index.

Let's assume that we have a function that verify if a number is a `prime number`, and we have an array with the candidate numbers, than we can call the function in two different way:

```golang
var prime []int = []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23}

func TestIsPrimeByValue(t *testing.T) {
    for _, item := range prime {
        if !IsPrime(item) {
            t.Fail()
        }
    }
}

func TestIsPrimeByIndex(t *testing.T) {
    for i := range prime {
        if !IsPrime(prime[i]) {
            t.Fail()
        }
    }
}
```

With the first loop, we are iterating the `value` of the array.
With the second loop, we are iterating the `index` of the array. This is an example with `int`. You can replace the array with a string and iterate the bytes of the string.

Comment: The use of the _ was what I was l was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @awcflavin its only a convention for unused variable. The variable is still there

Comment: @Mugen: no, the `_` is not a convention, and not a variable; it's specifically an anonymous placeholder and has special meaning: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier